Phone stucked in bootloop
I changed boot.img file in my phone (Infinix smart 8+) using adb and it stuck in `a boot loop. I tried pressing and holding volume and power buttons but it doesn't work. Is there a way to fix boot loop?

Probably flashing a proper ROM will revive it.

@ChanganAuto adb doesn't see phone in bootloop

If so I would say you've bricked it. It's just a budget phone with the crappiest SoC so there's that, not a huge loss.

@ChanganAuto can replacing motherboard fix the bootloop? I don't wanna buy a new phone just because of this

You want to replace the motherboard - essentially making it a NEW phone - of an USD100 phone? Good luck finding one that doesn't cost more than a new, proper, budget phone from reputable brands like Xiaomi, Oppo, Huawei, etc.

@Rastrey: A new motherboard and getting it fitted will probably cost you more than a new budget phone. Take this as a lesson that rooting and flashing phones is not especially easy, and involves real risks of wrecking them.

@ChanganAuto I have always believed that you can work with a phone in the same way as with a PC. If the OS does not load, then you can always reinstall it. Now I don't think so and I hate phones

@Rastrey Phones are more similar to a PC than you think. The only difference is that phones have a bootloader instead of a BIOS/UEFI. On a PC if you break the BIOS then you won't be able to install an OS just like in your situation. The only difference on a PC is that this happens so often that manufacturer have implemented ways to recover from this situation by software (e.g. second fallback BIOS) or by replacing the BIOS flash chip.
